# Animate Gradient View Upon Cell Selection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, gradient

I am looking to implement an animation to the gradient view.

Any steps to help with that? Currently I have everything ready and a static background attached to the cells which shows up on selection and hides when not selection. The hard part is the animation work with which I require some assistance.

Comment: "Currently I have everything ready"  Where?  I don't see a single line of code.

Comment: You have everything ready. but you not shared any code. Please share code

Answer (score 0):

Your can try this method
->View Controller

```
class VC2: UIViewController {

// MARK:- IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var tblSample: UITableView!

// MARK:- Private Variables
private var SelectedCell: Int?

// MARK:- View Lifecycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initialConfig()
}

// MARK:- Initial Config
private func initialConfig() {
    tblSample.delegate = self
    tblSample.dataSource = self
    
    } 
}
```

//Table View Delegate

```
extension VC2: UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    SelectedCell = indexPath.row
    tblSample.reloadData()
    }
}
```

// Table DataSource

```
extension VC2: UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    if SelectedCell == indexPath.row {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,delay: 0.5, options: .curveEaseIn) {
                cell.contentView.applyGradient(colours: [.white,.blue])
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
   }
}
```

// View Extension for apply and remove gradient

```
extension UIView {

@discardableResult
func applyGradient(colours: [UIColor]) -> CAGradientLayer {
    return self.applyGradient(colours: colours, locations: nil)
}

@discardableResult
func applyGradient(colours: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]?) -> CAGradientLayer {
    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.cgColor }
    gradient.locations = locations
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    return gradient
}

func removeGradient() {
    for lay in self.layer.sublayers ?? [] {
        if lay is CAGradientLayer {
            lay.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }
  }
}
```